# To display an array with index position using php

Tags: php, arrays

I am having arrays with objects in it and trying to return an array with index position.

I have this array

```
  Array
  (
    [id] => 174
    [timestamp] => 2016-08-25 13:08:11
   )
  Array
  (
    [id] => 161
    [timestamp] => 2016-07-21 13:27:33
   )
  Array
  (
   [id] => 160
   [timestamp] => 2016-07-21 10:35:45
  )
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
Array
  (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 174
        [timestamp] => 2016-08-25 13:08:11                                                     
     )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 161
        [timestamp] => 2016-07-21 13:27:33
    )
 [2] => Array
    (
        [id]=> 160
        [timestamp] => 2016-07-21 10:35:45
     )
 )
```

Is there any function to do this?
This is the code I used to display the array

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search_export'])){
    $result_array = unserialize($_REQUEST['export_arr']);
    $objRes = json_decode(json_encode($result_array), true);
    foreach ($objRes as $resarr) {
        $que_ans_val = unserialize($resarr['ques_ans']);
        $que_ans = json_decode(json_encode($que_ans_val), true);
        $resarr['ques_ans'] = implode(',',$que_ans);
        $array_first = array_splice($resarr,0,1);
        $array_middle = array_splice($resarr,0,23);
        $array_last = array_splice($resarr,0,22);
        $results =  $array_first + $array_last + $array_middle;
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($results);
    }
```

Comment: loop and than save in new array

Comment: Take new array and store your data in it with loop

Comment: How do you create this array? Is it from a database??

Comment: Yes, from database.

Comment: At least show us what have you done so far? database? the looping through the rows.

Answer (score 3):

Thats some wierd code, but this should do what you want in the simplest way I can think of

```
$results[] = $array_first 
$results[] = $array_last 
$results[] = $array_middle;
echo "<pre>" . print_r($results, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: This is not the place i need to change.actually, what i did this section($array_first = array_splice($resarr,0,1);
        $array_middle = array_splice($resarr,0,23);
        $array_last = array_splice($resarr,0,22);
        $results =  $array_first + $array_last + $array_middle;)is to bring two field which was in the last position to first.

Comment: If you want those arrays in a different order, then just change the order that the 3 lines are coded in

Comment: Its getting correctly,I just want to display my array as i have given above

Comment: And in what way is this not doing that?

Comment: I'm a fresher, don't know how to do that exactly,Anyways by that code i got it correctly. Now I need to display that array as i mentioned, for which I am trying from the last four hours.Can you help me out!!

Comment: The `print_r()` should display your array! Are you after some specific layout?

Answer (score 1):

store all arrays in one array and retrive it.
like:

```
$arr = array($array1,$array2,$array3);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Some dollar signs in that code might make it valid PHP